# Why is my tableView variable returning nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am using a `UISearchController` in my project. I initiate the search controller by supplying the `init(searchResultsController)` method with an `UIViewController` object that manages a tableView. The code for this object is:

```objc
import UIKit

class ResultsTableViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var list: [String] = []

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
 }
}

extension ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate{}

extension ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

     if cell == nil {
         cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
         cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
      } else {
         cell?.textLabel!.text = list[indexPath.row]
      }
       return cell!
     }
}
```

Furthermore, when I try to access the `resultsTableViewController.tableView` from the `updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)` method of the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol to populate its "list" array, it gives me an error. The tableView returns nil and the app crashes. I would like to point out that I have connected the data source, delegate, and the `IBOutlet` variable of the tableView to the appropriate view controller. I was hoping for someone to explain to me why this happens? I think I have a misunderstanding in the life cycle of the `ResultsTableViewController`. Lastly, when I drag a TableViewController from the storyboard instead of making my own table view controller from scratch everything works smoothly without any errors! Can you please help me understand whats going on here?

Edit: The code for my initial view controller is:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var resultsTableViewController  = ResultsTableViewController()
    var searchController: UISearchController!
    let list  = ["Apple", "Orange", "Bananas","Kiwi", "Cucumbers", "Apricot","Peach", "Cherry", "Mangosteen","Strawberry", "Blueberry", "Raspberry","Watermelon", "Persimmon", "plums","Papaya", "Jackfruit", "Lichi"]
    var filteredList: [String]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpSearchController()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func setUpSearchController(){
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableViewController)
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
    }

}

extension FirstViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return list.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        }else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }

}

extension FirstViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating{

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredList = list.filter({
            item in
            return item.containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!)
        })
        resultsTableViewController.list = filteredList
        resultsTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the instance of `ResultsTableViewController` ?

Comment: Yes I do. It is called resultsTableViewController.

Comment: No, I mean show the code where you *create* that instance, or is it your initial view controller.  The symptoms you are describing are consistent with not creating the view controller from the storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var resultsTableViewController  = ResultsTableViewController()`

creates a new `ResultsTableViewController` but it isn't linked to your storyboard scene, so none of the `@IBOutlet`s will be set.  You need to set an identifier for your scene (say *resultsViewController*) and then use that to instantiate the view controller from the storyboard:

```
var resultsTableViewController: ResultsTableViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpSearchController()
}

func setUpSearchController(){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    self.resultsTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifer("resultsViewController") as! ResultsTableViewController

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableViewController)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: I have a view controller (with a table view in it) in my storyboard that has ResultsTableViewController as its identity. So I think it is hooked up properly to the storyboard? @Paulw11

Comment: Yes, but when you say `var resultsTableViewController  = ResultsTableViewController()` it doesn't use anything from the storyboard, it just creates an 'empty' instance of the class, so your outlets are nil.  You need to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` as I have shown in order to get the objects to be connected

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @Paulw11 FOR POINTING OUT THAT NIL INSTANCE SCENARIO!!